How to compensate sudden changes of the input to the nonlinear system?
I am sorry if I have chosen wrong forum for my question. At first glance it maybe seems to be an "electrical" question but I would say that core of this question lays in control theory. Let's say I have below given buck converter loaded with a battery

I have been controlling the current through the inductor via a current
controller $D$ (basically a PI controller with a duty cycle at its output).

I have been thinking about a method how to respect in the current control
loop a fact that the input voltage $E$ can change suddenly (nearly step
changes). I have started my considerations from the dynamic model of the converter.
Operation of the converter can be described by following differential equation
$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}i_L = \frac{1}{L}\left(E\cdot u - R\cdot i_L - v_{bat}\right),$
where $u$ is the switching signal for the transistor ($u=1$ the transistor is on and $u=0$ the transistor is off). In case I apply averaging over the switching period to the above given differential equation I can write
$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left<i_L\right> = \frac{1}{L}\left(E\cdot\alpha - R\cdot \left<i_L\right> - 
 v_{bat}\right),$
where $\alpha$ is the duty cycle. In my opinion it's basically a nonlinear model due to the presence of the $E\cdot\alpha$ term. In case I linearize the model at a steady state operating point $(\alpha_0, \left<i_L\right>_0)$ I have following deviation model
$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\tilde{\left<i_L\right>} = \frac{1}{L}\left(E\cdot\tilde{\alpha} - R\cdot\tilde{\left<i_L\right>} - v_{bat}\right),$
where $\tilde{\left<i_L\right>},\tilde{\alpha}$ are deviations from the steady state operating point values. The linearized model can be transformed via the Laplace transform and a transfer function can be written
$G_1(s) = \frac{\tilde{I_L}(s)}{\tilde{\alpha}(s)} = \frac{\frac{E}{L}}{s + \frac{R}{L}}$
Based on the above given transfer function it seems to me that the changes in the input voltage $E$ results in changes of the dc gain of the converter. I think that the solution could be to use the gain-scheduling algorithm for elimination of the influence of the $E$. I am not sure whether I have made a mistake somewhere in my considerations. May I ask you for your opinion? Thank you in advance.

The electrical engineering stack exchange also has multiple relevant tags. But instead of linearizing $\alpha$ you could also choose to use $x=E,\alpha$ as input variable that you linearize since that is the resulting applied voltage.

@KwinvanderVeen thank you for your reaction. Your comment led me to the answer below.

In case I extend the steady state operating point by the input voltage $E_0$
I can write the deviation model in following form
$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\tilde{\left<i_L\right>} = \frac{1}{L}\left(\alpha_0\cdot\tilde{E} + E_0\cdot\tilde{\alpha} - R\cdot\tilde{\left<i_L\right>}\right),$
The Laplace transform of this equation gives
$\tilde{I_L}(s)=\frac{\frac{\alpha_0}{L}}{s + \frac{R}{L}}\cdot\tilde{E}(s) + \frac{\frac{E_0}{L}}{s + \frac{R}{L}}\cdot\tilde{\alpha}(s) = W(s)\cdot\tilde{E}(s) + G(s)\cdot\tilde{\alpha}(s),$ where the $W(s)$ is the transfer function of the disturbance i.e. deviation of the input voltage from the steady state value. Based on that I would say that I can compensate the sudden changes of the input voltage in following feedforward manner

I have verified viability of this method via a Scilab simulation with below given experiments

step changes of the input voltage $E$ without the feedforward compensation



step changes of the input voltage $E$ with the feedforward compensation


